# tflearn to_categorical: Processing data from pandas.df.values: array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tflearn, one-hot-encoding

```
labels = np.array([['positive'],['negative'],['negative'],['positive']])
# output from pandas is similar to the above
values = (labels=='positive').astype(np.int_)
to_categorical(values,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

If I remove the inner list enclosing for each element, it seems to work just fine

```
labels = np.array([['positive'],['negative'],['negative'],['positive']])
values = (labels=='positive').astype(np.int_)
to_categorical(values.T[0],2)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Why is it behaving this way? I'm following some tutorials, but they seem to have gotten the right output even for array of arrays. Is that recently upgraded to behave this way?

I'm using `tflearn (0.3.2)` on `py362`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the `to_categorical`:

```
def to_categorical(y, nb_classes):
    """ to_categorical.

    Convert class vector (integers from 0 to nb_classes)
    to binary class matrix, for use with categorical_crossentropy.

    Arguments:
        y: `array`. Class vector to convert.
        nb_classes: `int`. Total number of classes.

    """
    y = np.asarray(y, dtype='int32')
    if not nb_classes:
        nb_classes = np.max(y)+1
    Y = np.zeros((len(y), nb_classes))
    Y[np.arange(len(y)),y] = 1.
    return Y
```

The core part is the *advanced indexing* `Y[np.arange(len(y)),y] = 1`, which treats the input vector `y` as column index in the result array; So `y` needs to be a 1d array to work properly, you will generally get a broadcasting error for an arbitrary 2d array:

For instance:

```
to_categorical([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 2)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 to_categorical([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 2)
>
> c:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_utils.py
>   in to_categorical(y, nb_classes)
>        40         nb_classes = np.max(y)+1
>        41     Y = np.zeros((len(y), nb_classes))
>   ---> 42     Y[np.arange(len(y)),y] = 1.
>        43     return Y
>        44
>
> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast
>   together with shapes (2,) (2,3)

Either of these methods works fine:

```
to_categorical(values.ravel(), 2)
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

to_categorical(values.squeeze(), 2)
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

to_categorical(values[:,0], 2)
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: has this been updated recently? Take a look at [this](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/commit/3065d99749e46eb5ff27a48d6a18d887d1f2b2cb) notebook, i was stuck in that Y `In [12]`, which seem to have executed flawless before, but only now someone has pushed an update with `[xxx ,0]`

Comment: It could also be that the previous `Y` is a pandas series and now `Y` has been changed to a one column data frame. Just a guess.